# How to specify a double integral to find the area of a circle with radius $r$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**Problem:**

*Use double integrals to compute the area of un circle with radius $r$.*

**Solution:**

The angle $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$ (*i.e.*, the entire circumference), and the radius $r$ starts at the origin $0$ and reaches a given length for the radius, suppose it is $R$.

With that information, I can propose the following double integral:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{R}r\ drd\theta$$

Does the way I have defined the limits are correct?

I know that a circle is defined by $x^{2}+y^{2}=r^{2}$. Why the integration function does not incorporates that definition?

Comment: It is correct but it is much elegant using a single integral.

Comment: @Rohan How would you go about doing this using a single integral?

Comment: It does incorporate that definition. The reason why you know that a switch to polar requires $r dr d\theta$ instead of just $dr d\theta$ is because of that definition of $r$.

Comment: @InfZero You would write an equation for a (piece of a) circle of radius $r$ and integrate to find the area.  For example, one quarter of the circle is $x^2+y^2=r^2, x,y \ge 0$.  So the area of the circle is $$4\int_0^r y \; dx=4\int_0^r \sqrt{r^2-x^2} \; dx$$

Comment: @Rohan But in this context, your integrand is gotten by integrating $1$ with respect to $y$ from $0$ to $\sqrt{r^2 - x^2}$. So in the end, you really do have a double integral like this:$$\int_0^r\int_0^{\sqrt{r^2 - x^2}}dy\,dx$$I know that this is nitpicky, but this exact nit is the _point_ of this exercise in my opinion.